# Stay vs continue

Tags: vocabulary

> "We do this in order to preserve a regional tradition from centuries
>   ago."
>
> Q. the word "preserve" is closest in meaning to  (A) stay (B) continue

Why is the (B) a right answer? 'Stay' has mean particular state and situation also. And 'continue' has mean too. Is this case, both 'stay' and 'continue' are right answer?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Stack Exchange sites have their own peculiarities. For example, comments can be deleted at a whim, so it's better to put your information into the question text itself. You can use the [edit] link to do this, then delete the comment (hover your mouse over the comment and click the 'x' that appears).

Answer (score 1):

The "Q" is worded poorly.

You could argue that *preserving* something makes it 'stay'.

However, if you want to replace the word *preserve* with one of the two options, 'stay' doesn't quite fit. If pushed, it would likely take on the following meaning:

> **stay** *verb*
>   4 (with object) Stop, delay, or prevent (something), in particular suspend or postpone (judicial proceedings) or refrain from pressing (charges).
>   ‘Accordingly the Divisional Court allowed the appeal, remitted the matter to the arbitrator and stayed the oppression remedy proceeding.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/stay)

To 'stay' a tradition might be interpreted in the same way as to 'stay a motion', that is, to make it stop. If that interpretation is admissible, then it would be a somewhat unexpected outcome (doing something to derail a centuries-old tradition), but it would be at least grammatical.

The more straightforward choice is to replace *preserve* with *continue*: the action is done to carry on the centuries-old tradition.

Answer (score 0):

I would not replace preserve with either word.

'Preserve', here, means more something like 'to maintain and to protect'
or 'to keep in place'